# Splitting pdf file is very slow in server?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am uploading a `.pdf` file and at the time of uploading I am spliting that `.pdf` file. Like if the `.pdf` has 20 pages then I am splitting (using iTextsharp) it into 20 `.pdf` of one page each.

This process is going fast on my local machine but after hosting in IIS it is taking more time.

Ex: if I upload a 7 MB `.pdf` file (with 23 pages) to my local machine, it is taking 10 sec-15 sec for uploading and splitting.

For the same scenario in server it is taking 1 - 3 minutes.

Please help me.

Comment: Splitting speed depends on how you split and on the nature of the documents. Obviously, it also depends on the hardware. If the CPU of your server is slower than the CPU of your local machine, then the process will be slower on the server. There's also the matter of server load. A server may have plenty of resources, but if these resources aren't allocated to your process due to heavy load, then your process won't benefit from them. All in all, this doesn't look like a StackOverflow question.

Comment: You also include uploading into the equation. Uploading a 7 MB file from your local machine to your local machine, should be much faster than uploading a 7 MB file over, let's say, a wireless internet connection in a hotel room. You don't say anything about the difference in processing time for the splitting process.

Comment: I'm with @BrunoLowagie, we need to ignore the time spent uploading the file since that's a physical and economical constraint that we can't fix. We need to benchmark **only** the time spent splitting the file. This can be gauged by **not** uploading the file and instead just splitting a test file on the server's local file system. Until we get this data and the code used to split the PDF I'm for closing this.

Comment: Having written the code in a different toolkit to do exactly this task, I can tell you that implemented correctly, this is going to be completely IO bound and neither CPU nor memory bound. Also, PDF streams need to be seekable, so if you're operating on a wrapper stream around the active upload, you're effectively hosed until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be multiple issues going on here. As @Bruno Lowagie and @Chris Haas have mentioned, the problem might be caused by your upload bandwidth.

A possible solution to this problem would be to split up the two processes. Do the upload first, and check the time it took to complete that process. Then start processing the PDF file in a separate thread, and time that as well. This would help you narrow down where the problem lies. Also, make sure that your server isn't running any heavy processes in the background as this might skew the benchmark results, and steer you in the wrong direction.

If you are having a bandwidth issue, you might need to increase the bandwidth available.